Same code but different output in VS Code and Jupyter Notebook for Python
I am getting different output for same code in VS Code and Jupyter Notebook. Both are running same version of Python 3.11.5 My code is pretty simple:
x = 257
y = 257
print(x is y)

Output in Jupyter Notebook is False while VS code, outputs True. I have tried it both on Windows and Mac but same result.
Can someone please explain me why ?

The difference is due object interning in Python. Small numbers are cached so they point to same memory location.For numbers outside this range,new objects are created.
In VS Code optimizations may result in x is y return True for 257 because both variables refer to the same object.In Jupyter Notebook different objects might be created so x is y returns False
To check equality use ==, not is.

According to Python doc, Python creates same memory for integers from  -5 to 256, then how come editors override this ? Please check this link: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Editors like VS Code or environments like JupyterNotebook dont override Python’s behavior, instead they provide different execution context thatcan influence how Python compiler and interpreter handle object interning.
When variables assigned in same code block, the compiler may store the constant 257 once and reference it multiple times.During compilation it may perform constant folding and interning for immutable objects including integers, regardless of their value

The behavior you're observing is due to how Python handles integer objects in memory, particularly for small integers.
In Jupyter Notebook, it seems that the two integer objects x and y (both 257) are created as separate instances, hence x is y evaluates to False.
In VS Code, it appears that both x and y refer to the same integer object in memory, resulting in x is y being True.
